# Как используя String.format вывести выражение x + y в виде строки?

Tags: java, строки

Имея:

```
System.out.println(String.format("bla bla = %d", 2 + 3));
```

нужен вывод:

> 2 + 3 = 5

P.S. Решение в лоб:

```
System.out.println(String.format("2 + 3 = %d", 2 + 3));
```

не интересно так как не универсально

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.out.println(String.format("bla bla = %d", 2 + 3));
```

Дело в том, что в момент выполнения приложения `2 + 3` не существует. Компилятор наверняка его сворачивает до константы `5`. И даже если бы не сворачивал, это просто арифметическое выражение, с которым нельзя работать как с функцией, например выделять из него аргументы (исходные значения).

Что можно сделать: написать метод, принимающий два числа. Складывать их с помощью `+`, а печатать с помощью `String.format`.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d + %d = %d", a, b, a + b));
```